# Make directive by jquery datepicker

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I have made a directive by using jquery ui datepicker is following code

```
app.directive('jqdatepicker', ['$parse', '$filter', function ($parse, $filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            //Used to parse date format
            function formatter(value) {
                if (value) {
                    return jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(options.dateFormat, value);
                }
                return null;
            }

            //Used to parse date format
            function parseDate(value) {
                if (angular.isString(value)) {
                    return jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(options.dateFormat, value);
                }
                return null;
            }

            //select date
            var updateModel = function (dateText) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                });
            };

            //date picker options
            var options = {
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    updateModel(dateText);
                }
            };

            //parsing
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(formatter);
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(parseDate);

            // If we don't destroy the old one it doesn't update properly when the config changes
            element.datepicker('destroy');
            //bind datepicker
            element.datepicker(options);
            // Force a render to override whatever is in the input text box
            //ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Use of directive

```
<input ng-if="VM_Volunteer.isEdit" type="text" jqdatepicker class="form-control" ng-model="VM_Volunteer.dateOfBirth">
```

When i select date, the date is setting to my textbox, it has no problem, but after save this date to my database, then i am getting this date and want to show into this textbox, but date is not showing. When i getting this date, the it is formate date. What is the problem of me.

Comment: simple scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() { /* set value in jquery datepicker*/}) should work. Or use ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners

Comment: @PetrAveryanov,Thanks to your reply. I have used this function, but if i use this like as element.datepicker("setDate", value); the date is not right. it is being changed from actual date.